# How to wrap WrapPanel children in a TreeView?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a TreeView containing a parent and a couple of children. The children in turn consist of a WrapPanel with children of its own ("One", "Two", "Three" etc). How can I get these last elements to wrap when the parent window isn't large enough to accommodate them?

Here's my code:

```
<TreeView ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">

    <TreeViewItem Header="Parent" IsExpanded="True" >

        <ItemsControl>
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.Items>
                <TextBlock Text="One" />
                <TextBlock Text="Two" />
                <TextBlock Text="Three" />
                <TextBlock Text="Four" />
                <TextBlock Text="Five" />
                <TextBlock Text="Six" />
                <TextBlock Text="Seven" />
                <TextBlock Text="Eight" />
                <TextBlock Text="Nine" />
                <TextBlock Text="Ten" />
            </ItemsControl.Items>
        </ItemsControl>

        <ItemsControl>
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.Items>
                <TextBlock Text="One" />
                <TextBlock Text="Two" />
                <TextBlock Text="Three" />
                <TextBlock Text="Four" />
                <TextBlock Text="Five" />
                <TextBlock Text="Six" />
                <TextBlock Text="Seven" />
                <TextBlock Text="Eight" />
                <TextBlock Text="Nine" />
                <TextBlock Text="Ten" />
            </ItemsControl.Items>
        </ItemsControl>

    </TreeViewItem>

</TreeView>
```

And here's what it currently produces:

[image]

Comment: By setting width to ItemsControl/WrapPanel to you can achieve wrapping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, test this workaround. You must add `SizeChanged="TreeView_SizeChanged"` to the `TreeView` item.

```
private void TreeView_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var treeView = (TreeView) sender;
    foreach (TreeViewItem treeViewItem in treeView.Items)
    {
        foreach (ItemsControl ic in treeViewItem.Items)
        {
            Point relativeLocation = ic.TranslatePoint(new Point(0, 0), treeView);
            var wpMaxWidth = treeView.ActualWidth - relativeLocation.X;

            WrapPanel itemsWp = GetVisualChild<WrapPanel>(ic);
            itemsWp.MaxWidth = wpMaxWidth;
        }
    }
}

private static T GetVisualChild<T>(DependencyObject parent) where T : Visual
{
    int numVisuals = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent);
    for (int i = 0; i < numVisuals; i++)
    {
        Visual v = (Visual) VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
        var child = v as T;
        return child ?? GetVisualChild<T>(v);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Solution 2: Using `MultiBinding` and `IMultiValueConverter`.

```
...
<WrapPanel.MaxWidth>
    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource Converter1}">
        <MultiBinding.Bindings>
            <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}"/>
            <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType=TreeView}"/>
        </MultiBinding.Bindings>
    </MultiBinding>
</WrapPanel.MaxWidth>
...
```

The `IMultiValueConverter` `Convert` method implementation:

```
...
public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    var wp = values[0] as WrapPanel;
    var tv = values[1] as TreeView;
    if (wp == null || tv == null)
        return 0d;

    Point relativeLocation = wp.TranslatePoint(new Point(0, 0), tv);
    var wpMaxWidth = tv.ActualWidth - relativeLocation.X;
    return wpMaxWidth;
}
...
```

**NOTE:** You must refresh the `Binding` after the container size change.

Comment: Thanks dbvega. I'm using MVVM so I tried the second method and it works fine. I didn't have to refresh the binding though, if I modify the MultiBinding to also bind to the TreeView's "ActualWidth" then it will get invoked whenever the size changes. I also had to add an extra couple of lines to take into account the width of the vertical scrollbar, if visible. I was hoping there was a way to solve this question using regular WPF layout properties but if nobody posts a solution that does it like that in the next day or so then I'll mark this one as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I modified [dbvega's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2322038/dbvega) solution 2 to take vertical scrollbar width and vertical scrollbar visibility in to account. Also added recalculation on treeview width change.
XAML:

```
...
<WrapPanel.Width>
  <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource Converter1}">
    <MultiBinding.Bindings>
        <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}"/>
        <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ScrollViewer}"/>
        <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ScrollViewer}" Path="ViewportWidth"/>
    </MultiBinding.Bindings>
  </MultiBinding>
</WrapPanel.Width>
...
```

Converter:

```
...
object IMultiValueConverter.Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    foreach (var v in values)
        if (v is null)
           return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
    var panel = (Panel)values[0];
    var scrollviewer = (ScrollViewer)values[1];

    Point relativeLocation = panel.TranslatePoint(new Point(0, 0), scrollviewer);
        var width = scrollviewer.ViewportWidth - relativeLocation.X;

    return width;
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

It's been a few years since I asked this question, and I've learned a lot more about WPF layouts in the interim. This can, in fact, be done in XAML alone, which I'll post now for anyone stumbling across this in future. The key is to template out TreeViewItem and examine the XAML it uses to populate each level of the tree.

In short, each level of a TreeView consists of a grid containing two rows and three columns. The first row is for the TreeViewItem header, while the second is for the children.

There are also three columns. Column 0 is for the expander icon, column 1 is for the header content and column 2 is for all the remaining space. The children all sit in a ContentPresenter which takes up columns 1 and 2 on the second row. The column definitions for this grid reveal something interesting:

```
<ColumnDefinition MinWidth="19" Width="Auto"/>
<ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
<ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
```

The expander icon is, by default, 16x16, but column 0 has MinWidth set to 19 pixels. So unless you change that expander icon, 19 pixels will be the indent to the start of the ContentPresenter. Thus, all you need to do is bind each child ItemsControl to the width of its TreeViewItem and give it a padding of 19 pixels (or whatever the width of your expander icon is) on the *right*-hand side:

```
<ItemsControl Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType= {x:Type TreeViewItem}, AncestorLevel=1}, Path=ActualWidth}" Padding="0 0 19 0">
```

The result is pixel-perfect wrapping:

[image]

(Note that this solution will also accommodate scrollbars appearing and disappearing, and will re-arrange the WrapPanel items accordingly when they do).